# Why does Android Lint say "Call requires API level 8 (Current min is 8)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

I could understand if the API level required by the call was higher than the minimum, but why should it be a problem if it's *equal* to the minimum?

Comment: Let me guess you are using `Android Studio` and seeing this error?

Comment: Yes, in Android Studio.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks. check the link

Comment: It's an Android Studio bug

Comment: OK, I am just going to suppress the warning, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in Android Studio 0.1. It is fixed for 0.1.1

See fix: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58798/1

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem in Android Studio; it was not a problem in IntelliJ which I had been using prior to AS.

To "fix it" I simply used the [TargetApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html) annotation:

```
@TargetApi(8)
```

I only added it to my main Activity and the warnings went away everywhere.

Comment: Awesome! If you conditionally load a class when `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > n`, then putting `@TargetApi(n)` on that class will suppress the undesired red warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`look at `uses-sdk` and value of `android:minSdkVersion`. Make sure specified sdk version has level equal or higher then 8.

Comment: The minimum SDK level is set to 8, that's why I don't understand why it's complaining about an API level 8 call.

Comment: When using the gradle build, set `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.grade` instead of the `<uses-sdk>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`. *Still,* Android Studio 0.6.1 is warning that some layout resources "requires API level 11 (current min is 1)" even though it's set to 13.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has some lint problems because I have this same problem too. The project should still build though. if not just do a simple check for the build version

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1){
    //code goes here
}
```

and that should suppress the lint check